# Numpy - Array addition using previous value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

this is how I would code something, where "minute" and "errands" are lists of the same size (examples below).

But instead these are two numpy arrays, so this code doesn't work. The other thing being I'd like the result "done" to be a numpy array as well.

```
done = 0
for i in minute:
    if done < minute:
        done = minute + (errands * 2)
    else:
        done = done + (errands * 2)
    print (done)
```

So, I have also tried using "np.where"

```
import numpy as np
done = 0
done = np.where(done < minute, minute + (errands * 2), done + (errands * 2))
print(done)
```

This would be perfect, but the problem here is that it doesn't continuously update "done" so that at some point the equivalent code of "done = done + (errands * 2)" would run (if that makes sense).

Some small examples of the numpy array:

```
minute = np.array([2, 2, 5, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 15])

errands = np.array([1, 1, 1, 7, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
```

Just so I can be as clear as possible I would like the output of "done" to be

```
done = np.array([4, 6, 8, 22, 26, 30, 32, 34, 36])
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `for i in minute: if done < minute: ` I don't see how this can work, you're comparing done, which is a number to a numpy array `minute` for each element of that `minute`.

Comment: The code is confusing because of the naming of `done` both as variable as numpy array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an iterative problem because of the updating.  However, it is O(n), and can be done efficiently using `numba` and `njit`:

***Setup***

```
from numba import njit
```

You may have to `pip install numba`

---

```
@njit
def toggle(a, b):
    done, out = 0, []    
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if done < a[i]:
            done = a[i] + (b[i] * 2)
        else:
            done = done + (b[i] * 2)
        out.append(done)
    return np.array(out)

toggle(minute, errands)
```

```
array([ 4,  6,  8, 22, 26, 30, 32, 34, 36], dtype=int64)
```

---

***Performance***

```
minute = np.repeat(minute, 10000)
errands = np.repeat(errands, 10000)

%timeit toggle(minute, errands)
2.02 ms ± 9.84 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit toggle_no_njit(minute, errands)
64.4 ms ± 738 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with numpy alone:

```
def smart(m, e):
    e = 2*e
    r = np.empty(e.size+1, e.dtype)
    r[0] = 0
    e.cumsum(out=r[1:])
    return r[1:] + np.maximum.accumulate(m - r[:-1])
```

Test and timings:
Set up random problem of size 1000:

```
>>> e = np.random.uniform(1, 3, 1000)
>>> m = np.random.uniform(1, 7, 1000).cumsum()
```

Gives same result as numba:

```
>>> np.allclose(toggle(m, e), smart(m, e))
True
```

But considerably faster even when compile time is excluded:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: toggle(m, e))
21.466296120896004
>>> timeit(lambda: smart(m, e))
11.608282678993419
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Numba` to accomplish this task very efficiently.

But avoid using lists whenever possible, as @user3483203 did in his answer. Lists come with a very high overhead, since Numba can't directly work on lists [2.6.2.4.1. List Reflection](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html)

**Example**

```
@nb.njit
def toggle_2(a, b):
    done=0.
    out=np.empty(a.shape[0],dtype=a.dtype)

    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        if done < a[i]:
            done = a[i] + (b[i] * 2)
        else:
            done = done + (b[i] * 2)
        out[i]=done
    return out
```

**Performance**

```
e = np.random.uniform(1, 3, 1_000)
m = np.random.uniform(1, 7, 1_000).cumsum()

Paul Panzer (smart) : 13.22 µs
user3483203 (toggle): 18.47 µs
toggle_2              2.47  µs

e = np.random.uniform(1, 3, 1_000_000)
m = np.random.uniform(1, 7, 1_000_000).cumsum()

Paul Panzer (smart) : 15.97 ms
user3483203 (toggle): 30.28 ms
toggle_2              3.77  ms
```